# Which algorithm to choose for a huge integer multiplication, depending on N size

Tags: algorithm

In my free time I'm preparing for interview questions like: *implement multiplying numbers represented as arrays of digits*. Obviously I'm forced to write it from the scratch in a language like `Python` or `Java`, so an answer like "use GMP" is not acceptable (as mentioned here: [Understanding Schönhage-Strassen algorithm (huge integer multiplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861958/understanding-sch%C3%B6nhage-strassen-algorithm-huge-integer-multiplication)).

For which exactly `range` of sizes of those 2 numbers (i.e. number of digits), I should choose

1. School grade algorithm
2. Karatsuba algorithm
3. Toom-Cook
4. Schönhage–Strassen algorithm ?

Is Schönhage–Strassen `O(n log n log log n)` always a good solution? Wikipedia mentions that Schönhage–Strassen is advisable for numbers beyond `2^2^15` to `2^2^17`. What to do when one number is ridiculously huge (e.g. `10,000` to `40,000` decimal digits), but second consists of just couple of digits?

Does all those 4 algorithms parallelizes easily?

Comment: Schönhage-Strassen is definitely slower for small numbers, so it isn't always a good solution. Where it becomes better than say Toom-Cook would probably depend on the actual implementation. Specifically on where you choose the cutoff point, beyond which you just fall back on a simpler algorithm.

Comment: I don't think an interviewer will expect you to be able to implement Schönhagen-Strassen... To be honest I don't think there are many interviewers out there that would be able to pull off a NTT themselves. The simple quadratic algorithm should probably already be enough. The question of course is still interesting. It probably depends on how optimized your different implementations are. Experimentation can tell what the optimal ranges are

Comment: @NiklasB. I think you should be able to implement Karatsuba off the top of your head (it is very simple after all), then be able to explain how Toom-Cook is a generalisation of that, and for Schönhage-Strassen, simply knowing the principle behind it would be fine. Even if you know S-S inside out, there's probably no way you can implement it in Java from scratch within an hour.

Comment: I know that there are interview question like this, but from 40 years of software development experience, I can tell you that they are completely irrelevant. Companies that base their hiring on these questions get the developers they deserve. These developers can reproduce algorithms that have been invented by others and don't need to be re-implemented. And the concepts behind Karatsuba etc. can hardly be applied to anything else than multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library's source and see [their thresholds for switching between algorithms](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/arm/gmp-mparam.h).

More pragmatically, you should **just profile your implementation** of the algorithms. GMP puts a *lot* of effort into optimizing, so their algorithms will have different constant factors than yours. The difference could easily move the thresholds around by an order of magnitude. Find out where the times cross as input size increases for *your* code, and set the thresholds correspondingly.

I think all of the algorithms are amenable to parallelization, since they're mostly made up up of divide and conquer passes. But keep in mind that parallelizing is another thing that will move the thresholds around quite a lot.

Comment: +1 for recommending profiling! Performance-related decisions always need thorough profiling. Otherwise it's guesswork, and performance guesswork is wrong most of the time.